# Can I make TeX echo what the document sends to \write18?

Tags: shell-escape

I'd like to see what's being sent to the shell (if it is indeed a real shell and not some direct process-spawning) during compilation of my document.

(I've solved my original problem, but this remains as a curiosity.)

Comment: It's in the log ...

Comment: @JosephWright and not in standard out?

Comment: ... and from a TeX POV it's the same as using a `\message`

Comment: the terminal shows you the _result_ of `\write18`, but not he  `runsystem()` calls.